# Why do I sometimes regain an estus flask charge?

Tags: dark-souls-3

In Dark Souls 1 there was a similar mechanic where you would gain charges when someone "nearby" (as the game ruled) strengthed a bonfire. I don't see this mechanic yet in Dark Souls 3 and it seems to be happening in one of the first areas. Furthermore, it seems to happen after **I** kill an enemy. What governs this mechanic?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I randomly get more Estus Flasks?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32928/why-do-i-randomly-get-more-estus-flasks)

Comment: I don't see any reason to assume this question is a dupe, and I've listed several reasons why I don't think it is one.

Comment: @Yuuki This is about Dark Souls 3, not Dark Souls 1. Assuming the mechanics are the same is dangerous; even the possibility of only subtle differences warrants a new question.

Comment: I don't want to answer because I don't have reproducible results, but I believe that (like in DS1, where enemies would sometimes randomly drop humanity), enemies drop charges for the estus flask. Also, sometimes when I get summoned in--via white sign--and play with a player for awhile, my estus gets recharged.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ways to recover Estus Flasks [source](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/dark-souls-3/Things_Dark_Souls_3_Doesn't_Tell_You):

- Dying
- Resting at a Bonfire
- Having another player rate your message.
- Killing enemies. Tougher enemies increase the chance of having an Estus Flask restored.
- Killing invaders will give you 2 estus flasks