# How do estus charges work?

Tags: dark-souls-3

Can anyone advise how Estus Charges work?
I have an Estus Flask 10+7, but I'm not sure what the "+7" means.

Does it mean I get 17 uses of it? Because after 10 uses I'm no longer able to drink the Flask. Is there some way to recharge the flask to get 7 more uses without going back to a bonfire?

Answer (score 21):

The +7 next to your [Estus Flask](http://darksouls3.wikidot.com/estus-flask) doesn't have anything to do with how many times you can use the flask, it indicates how strong it is (aka how much HP or FP it restores per use). The 10 is your number of uses (aka you can use the flask 10 times before returning to a bonfire). There are a [few ways to regain Estus Flasks](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/262248/why-do-i-sometimes-regain-an-estus-flask-charge) without returning to a bonfire, but they're not reliable.

Your number of uses can be increased by giving the blacksmith [Estus Shards](http://darksouls3.wikidot.com/estus-shard), and the strength of the flask can be increased by  burning an [Undead Bone Shard](http://darksouls3.wikidot.com/undead-bone-shard) at the Firelink Shrine Bonfire.